# Conditional fields data options change

Tags: jquery, drupal, module, drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7 and I have the [Conditional Fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module installed. It works great until now and it helped me out a lot for what I had to create. 
Now I came to a point where I have to change the options of a Date field (Starting year and Ending year) depending on whether a checkbox is checked or not.
If anyone has any info on how that can be done and/or implemented into this module - please advise.
I noticed there is a custom jQuery field that can be filled when setting conditions on a field but I am not sure whether that may help me since I couldn't find any documentation on that anywhere.

Thank you!